# Access JpaEntityInformation in custom repository implementation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have some `Spring Data` repositories that are extended via fragments as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). This works fine as long as I only inject the `EntityManager` in this implementations.

One of those implementations is generic and therefor needs an instance of `JpaEntityInformation` for the current entity to work correctly (I basically only need the entity name and java type). If I try to "autowire" this in the constructor as well, I get an exception that says that no bean of class `JpaEntityInformation` could be found.

I understand this exception but I'd like to know whether there is another way to get name and class of the entity the current repository instance was created for. I thought that it should be possible to somehow get the `JpaEntityInformation` via the constructor because this is the way it is done if you specify a custom repository base class (which I don't want to do).

Below you can find a use case for what I just described.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FindByFieldRepositoryImpl<T> implements FindByFieldRepository<T> {

    private final JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation;
    private final EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public T findByField(String field, Object value) {
        return createQuery(field, value).getSingleResult();
    }

    private TypedQuery<T> createQuery(String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
        String entityName = entityInformation.getEntityName();
        Class<T> entityType = entityInformation.getJavaType();

        String queryString = String.format("FROM %s WHERE %s = :value", entityName, fieldName);
        TypedQuery<T> query = manager.createQuery(queryString, entityType);
        return query.setParameter("value", fieldValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `JpaEntityInformationSupport` to get entity information from its class. Here's how your code would look like:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FindByFieldRepositoryImpl<T> implements FindByFieldRepository<T> {

    private final EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public T findByField(String field, Object value, Class<T> clazz) {
        return createQuery(field, value, clazz).getSingleResult();
    }

    private TypedQuery<T> createQuery(String fieldName, Object fieldValue, Class<T> clazz) {
        JpaEntityInformation entityInformation = JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(clazz, manager);
        String entityName = entityInformation.getEntityName();
        Class<T> entityType = entityInformation.getJavaType();

        String queryString = String.format("FROM %s WHERE %s = :value", entityName, fieldName);
        TypedQuery<T> query = manager.createQuery(queryString, entityType);
        return query.setParameter("value", fieldValue);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but it should work.

Comment: The problem with this is, that you have to provide the class of the entity to each call of the findByField method, which is redundant information. So I wouldn't consider this a good solution. However, I'm not yet sure if there's a better one...